# VB6 what is the best way to check the ending characters of different lengths

Tags: vb6

Lets say I have several strings I have to inspect. Here is a list of them:

```
/gigs-services/online-marketing/
/gigs-services/;
/scrapersnbots-files/footer.php';?
/scrapersnbots-files/ratings.js
```

Lets say the name of the variable that holds each string is ***strUrls***
I need to filter out strings that end with  ***;***  and  ***;?***  and ***';?***

Is there a more efficient way to do so than this one below?

```
if right(strUrls,1) = ";" or right(strUrls,2) = ;? or right(strUrls,3) = ';?
```

Comment: Just some suggestions: The third check ( ';? ) would be caught by the second ( ;? ) since the last two chars are the same, so that would remove a check. The other suggestion is to do your checks in separate If blocks (or nested). VB6 will always evaluate all parts of the If, so it will be faster to separate the checks. If your first If evaluates to True and it can skip the others, it will save time.

Comment: If you assume that over time you might identify more cases, you might want to first build a list (collection?) of search suffixes, and then iterate through that list.